# Use of input/raw_input in python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-2.x, raw-input

I would like to set a user prompt with the following question:

> save_flag is not set to 1; data will not be saved. Press enter to continue.

`input()` works in python3 but not python2. `raw_input()` works in python2 but not python3. Is there a way to do this so that the code is compatible with both python 2 and python 3?

Comment: If you want compatibility you might want to use [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

Answer (score 64):

Bind `raw_input` to `input` in Python 2:

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```

Now `input` will return a string in Python 2 as well.

---

If you're using [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) to write 2/3 compatible code then `six.input()` there points to `raw_input()` in Python 2 and `input()` in Python 3.

Comment: Pylint on Python 2.7 doesn't like it: `Redefining built-in 'input' (redefined-builtin)`

Comment: Argh... Pylint is both a blessing and a curse. A blessing for n00bs to Python to help guide them in writing Python code; a curse to advanced Python charmers for slapping them for perfectly valid code. I would argue that Pylint is wrong in this case and it sucks to have to uglify your code with a `# pylint: disable` comment just to make some tool happy.

Comment: When I try to use this I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment` when using `input` afterwards, even when it's running Python 3

Comment: @ProQ That's because you're doing this inside a function / class. You need to do it outside, otherwise Python will think you are declaring a local variable, and it will not have a value if there is a NameError.

Comment: The path in `six` is now `six.moves.input`.

Answer (score 16):

I think the best way to do this is

```
import six

six.moves.input()
```

...it'll work across 2 and 3.

Answer (score 7):

Update: This method only works if you have future installed and the answers above are much better and more generalizable.

From [this cheatsheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) there is another method that looks cleaner:

```
# Python 2 and 3:
from builtins import input
```

Comment: In Python 2: `ImportError: No module named builtins`

Comment: ahh I had the future package installed and didn't realize it.

Comment: This answer is what I do, install the future package and then import from future and also use `from builtins import *` in every script.

Comment: most modern python training courses provide this code to overcome this problem: `if hasattr(__builtins__, 'raw_input'):
    input = raw_input`  (2nd line is indented under first).  The answer provided here did not work on an Anaconda distribution of iPython 2.7 and I see others reporting issues with this solution as well.  This answer should be deleted so people do not try to use it and run into trouble.

Comment: Oddly enough, I've had issues with `EOFError` using this method. `from six.moves import input` seems to work better for me

Answer (score 2):

This is because, In python 2, `raw_input()` accepts everything given to stdin, as a string, where as `input()` preserves the data type of the given argument (i.e. if the given argument is of type `int`, then it will remain as `int` only, but won't be converted to `string` as in case of `raw_input()`). That is basically, when `input()` is used, it takes the arguments provided in stdin as string, and evaluates the same. And this evaluation converts the argument to corresponding type.

```
# Python 2.7.6
>>> a = raw_input("enter :- ")
enter :- 3
>>> type(a)     # raw_input() converts your int to string
<type 'str'>
>>> a = input("enter :- ")
enter :- 3
>>> type(a)    # input() preserves the original type, no conversion     
<type 'int'> 
>>>
```

Therefore, while using `input()` in Python 2, user has to be careful while passing the arguments. If you are passing a string, you need to pass it with quote ( since python recognizes characters inside quote as string). Else `NameError` will be thrown.

```
 >>> a = input("enter name :- ")
 enter name :- Derrick
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'Derrick' is not defined
 >>> a = input("enter name :- ")
 enter name :- 'Derrick'
 >>> a
 'Derrick'
```

Whereas, if using `raw_input()`, you need not worry about the data type while passing the argument as everything it accepts as a string. But yes, inside your code you need to take care of appropriate type conversion.

To avoid this extra care needed for `input()` in Python 2, it has been removed in Python 3. And `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()` in Python 3. The functionality of `input()` from Python 2 is no more in Python 3. `input()` in Python 3 serves what `raw_input()` was serving in Python 2.

[This post](https://pabitrap.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/parsing-user-input-in-python-3/) might be helpful for a detailed understanding.

Comment: -1 although it is a nice explanation, it completely misses the question: *Is there a way to do this so that the code is compatible with both python 2 and python 3?*. The OP knows about the differences and is interested in a solution to the problem, not the explanation of it. Btw, the functionality of py2 input can be easily recovered with eval(input()) in py3, which makes your last sentences about the functionality, that is no more, obsolet. Yes, there is no single command, but a very simple recovery.

Comment: DO NOT use `eval` to replicate Py2 behaviour. That is not the equivalent of `input` in Py2.   Use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly load the function:

`from builtins import input`

Then you can use `input()` in python2 as well as python3.

You may have to install the dependency:

`pip install future`

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code in either python2 and use [futurize](http://python-future.org/futurize.html) or in python3 and use [pasteurize](http://python-future.org/pasteurize.html).
This removes the complexity of thinking about compatible code and guarantees good practices.

Regarding this specific question

```
from builtins import input
```

Is exactly what the above scripts produce.