# Taking input while accounting for both Python 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Since Python 2's `raw_input` was changed to just `input` for Python 3, I was wondering if there was a way to take input while accounting for both Python 2 and 3. I'm trying to write a script for both versions, and this input part is the only thing that's not working well.

I tried running just `input` with Py2, and this happens:

```
>>> a = input('Input: ')
inp: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    a = input('Input: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

I saw a workaround to quote the input:

```
>>> a = input('Input: ')
inp: "testing test"
a
'testing test'
```

Is there a way to concatenate the quote to the beginning and end of the input? `'"' + input('input: ') + '"'` isn't working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of input/raw\_input in python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731043/use-of-input-raw-input-in-python-2-and-3)

Comment: Never use Python 2 `input`, do as in the dupe instead

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a good practice, but you can use a `try` block to test whether the `raw_input()` is being recognized (thus telling you whether you're on Python 2.x or Python 3.x):

```
try:
    a = raw_input('input: ')
except NameError:
    a = input('input: ')
```

I would use `raw_input()` to test because it's not accepted by Python 3.x and is what you expect to use in Python 2.x, so the `input()` will not trigger in Python 2.x.

I'm not an expert so I'm sure there are better suggestions.

@Chris_Rands' [suggested dupe thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731043/use-of-input-raw-input-in-python-2-and-3) has a more elegant solution by binding `input = raw_input` so if you have multiple `input()`, you only need to `try` once.

Comment: Like you said, not a great way to do it say in production, but totally fine for a small personal throw away script.

Comment: I'm very much a beginner myself, so what's best practice is still very much unknown to me.  IMO having a script supported in both Python version seems like a weird idea anyhow.  Personally I would have branched it into two versions and have another main.py check the version to decide which script to fire up.

Answer (score -1):

This works for both Python 2 and 3.

```
from builtins import input
input("Type something safe please: ")
```