# How to not inspect error on raw_input with Python 2 compatible code

Tags: python, pycharm, compatibility, lint, intellij-inspections

I have a Python module that can be run with both Python 2 and Python 3.  At some point, the module takes a user input.  How it does so depends on the Python major version:

- Python 2: use `raw_input`
- Python 3: use `input`

My IDE is PyCharm, and my project interpreter is Python `3.8`.  PyCharm inspects an unresolved reference error on `raw_input`.

Besides a `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` tag, how can I get PyCharm not to complain about `raw_input`?  Is there some setting I can enable?

---

**Sample Code**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys


if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    some_input = input("Please give input: ")
else:
    some_input = raw_input("Please give input: ")

print("input: {}".format(some_input))
```

What I see on my screen:

[image: raw_input unresolved reference]

---

**Versions**

- Python: `3.8.2`
- PyCharm: `CE 2019.3.1`

My PyCharm has `Code compatibility inspection` enabled for Python `2.7`, `3.6`, `3.7`, and `3.8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment checks are not supported in PyCharm, consider using `input` from `six` (https://six.readthedocs.io/#module-six.moves).

Comment: Thank you @user2235698!  I found this answer also is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321967/11163122